# Blender Glitching Text and mesh

Tags: mesh, objects, text-object, font

I am trying to render an animation of my graduation project in Blender.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTeM0ja2mDc&ab_channel=MusicWithFreak

I have a problem which is glitching my texts and some of my mesh objects. At the very start of the video you can see that my mesh is "glitching black color" and after that when the camera is close to the pool, you can see glitching the fence as well. Texts "HFMN Industries" and "Fashion Icon" which you can see in the video at 0:50 and 1:21 are glitching and jumping like crazy. Project is bein rendered in EEVEE, 1920x1080 200% (100% do nothing) and 128 Render Sample (already lowered from 512).

Ambient Oclusion, Bloom, Screen Space Reflections, Motion Blur and Volumetric Lighting are turned on. My shadows are set to 1024px Cube Size and 1024px Cascade size - High Bit Depth is on and Soft shadows are off.

I really need your help guys, thank you for any ideas.

EDIT:

Examples of Glitching:

In my animation some of my meshes are constantly blinking and glitching from this:
[image: This is how it is supposed to look]

To this:
[image]

Same thing happens with some of my text objects. It looks like they are changing font or something.
As you can see both names of the buildings change from this:
[image]

To this:[image]

Comment: Oh, very good. I cannot tell the difference with the first two screenshots, but the second two screenshots are very clear. Why it is switching arbitrarily to blender’s internal font, I don’t know.

Comment: In those first 2 pictures is orangle light which is pointing the light on the cube. Under this cube is another cube which is glitching like crazy from black back to my material.

Comment: What GPU are you using, and does any of this happen in the viewport?

Comment: My main GPU is RTX 2060, tried also with GTX1050Ti with the same effect. It is not happening in my viewport. I was thinking of converting these two text objects into individual meshes?

Comment: Umm, maybe. I would file a bug report since this is not supposed to happen.

Comment: I am gonna try converting it into meshes and we will see. I will stay in touch. Thank you for now. I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Tried converting it into mesh with no result. So I tried to delete the text and create it again but still with that glitching error. I am starting to think maybe the font I am using is broken?

Comment: After you converted to mesh, is it in the correct font all the time, some of the time, or none of the time?

Comment: It is still blinking as before, nothing has changed

Comment: Ok that is really weird. Are you rendering to frames or video? Is this going through the Blender Sequencer?

Comment: Weird as hell, standard animation is being rendered, it is not going through sequencer.